# Converting directories of images to tfrecords using built-in inception script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to convert my data (images) into tfrecords.
I was led to this built-in script via Stackoverflow but I can't seem to get it working right.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/f87a58cd96d45de73c9a8330a06b2ab56749a7fa/research/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py

I have changed the default Flag values to reflect my values as such:

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('train_directory', r'D:\project\Moondra\BAD_IMAGES\BAD IMAGES TRAINING DATA\TEST 2\training',
                           'Training data directory')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('validation_directory', r''D:\project\Moondra\BAD_IMAGES\BAD IMAGES TRAINING DATA\TEST 2\validation',
                           'Validation data directory')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('output_directory', r''D:\project\Moondra\BAD_IMAGES\BAD IMAGES TRAINING DATA\TEST 2\tfrecords',
                           'Output data directory')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('train_shards', 2,
                            'Number of shards in training TFRecord files.')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('validation_shards', 2,
                            'Number of shards in validation TFRecord files.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_threads', 2,
                            'Number of threads to preprocess the images.')

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('labels_file','', r'D:\project\Moondra\BAD_IMAGES\BAD IMAGES TRAINING DATA\TEST 2\labels.txt')
```

The `training` directory format is, 5 subdirectories each which represent a label.

I have tried running the script but I run into the following error:

```
Saving results to D:\project\Moondra\BAD_IMAGES\BAD IMAGES TRAINING DATA\TEST 2\tfrecords
Determining list of input files and labels from D:\project\Moondra\BAD_IMAGES\BAD IMAGES TRAINING DATA\TEST 2\validation.

raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\cloud_test\train\convert_to_TFRECORDS.py", line 397, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Moondra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\cloud_test\train\convert_to_TFRECORDS.py", line 391, in main
    FLAGS.validation_shards, FLAGS.labels_file)
  File "C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\cloud_test\train\convert_to_TFRECORDS.py", line 377, in _process_dataset
    filenames, texts, labels = _find_image_files(directory, labels_file)
  File "C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\cloud_test\train\convert_to_TFRECORDS.py", line 330, in _find_image_files
    labels_file, 'r').readlines()]
  File "C:\Users\Moondra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 183, in readlines
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Users\Moondra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 80, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "C:\Users\Moondra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open:  : The system cannot find the path specified.

; No such process
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify both train and validation directory has correctly labeled data?
Labels should match with the labels file as well.
It's better to remove white space from the path. At times it also make bugs.
;)